# From hard coded if else if to configurable if else if loop

Tags: verilog

I have a verilog synthesizable code that has if else if statements.
It has fixed number of if else if statements as below.

```
always @ (*)
begin
    if (~a[0] && ~b[0] )
        c = 0;
    else if (~a[1] && ~b[1])
        c = 0;
    else if (~a[2] && ~b[2])
        c = 0;
    else if (~a[3] && ~b[3])
        c = 0;
    else if (~a[4] && ~b[4])
        c = 0;
    else
        c = 1;
end
```

Now I need to have the same functionality but make the number of if else if statements configurable through a parameter. Note that the priority set through the if else if statements need to be maintained. I guess I need to use a loop . But with a for loop, it will be like this:

```
always @ (*)
begin
    for (int i=0; i<param; i++)
    begin
        if (~a[i] && ~b[i] )
          c = 0;
        else
          c = 1;
     end
end
```

The above code does not mimic the if else if structure. rather it will make parallel if statements which is not the desired output.
I guess generate might be useful but not sure how to use it in this context. 
Can anyone suggest what is the best approach I should follow.

Thanks,
Anirban

Comment: Your second piece of code isn't complete, please edit it.

Comment: @Dray The second piece was complete, just not visible due to an error in the Markdown source.

Comment: @hexafraction oh! thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Dray Not a problem; I am happy to help.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow... Not sure how to format the coding. the second piece of code is simply the for loop with if and else statements which makes it as parallel if statements as there is no provision to add an else if statement. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For this specific case, we can reformulate your logic using a [reduction operator](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/operators2.html) to avoid the loop entirely:

```
assign c = ~|(~a & ~b);
```

This first takes the result of `~a & ~b` as a multi-bit value, ORs all of the bits together to get a single-bit result, and inverts that.

This can be reduced, through a chain of ["bubble pushing"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136288/) simplifications, to the elegantly simple:

```
assign c = &(a | b);
```

Comment: But how will it ensure priority. I don't want a[1] to be checked before or at the same time as a[0]. if a[0] satisfies, it should not even check a[1] and so on.

Comment: What does it mean, in terms of hardware, for a value to not be "checked"?

Comment: In an if - else if series, if the condition is met at some stage, it will come out and restart from the beginning.

Comment: @AnirbanMoitra You're still thinking of the `if` / `else` chain as a bunch of sequential steps. Stop looking at it that way. The entire `always` block has to compile to a set of logic gates, no matter whether you've used `if` or not.

Comment: @AnirbanMoitra A synthesis tool will take any `always @*` block and convert all the assignments to any variable into a single Boolean expression. An `if/else` statement is converted to a mux with the if condition selecting between two values generated by the true and false branches. When you chain `if/else` constructs, you are connecting the output of one mux into the input of the next mux. If you take all the logic generated for your RTL, it reduces to the Boolean logic equation @duskwuff shows.

Comment: @dave_59 Almost. `if/else` statements behave similarly to muxes, but they need not be implemented with muxes. (Keep in mind `if(a) b else c` is logically equivalent to `(a & b) | (~a & c)`, for instance.)

Comment: That _is_ the Boolean equation for a mux. How it gets mapped into hardware is irrelevant to this discussion. The point is when describing combinatorial logic in the form of procedural RTL statements, you always have a choice writing the same logic in equivalent Boolean equations. A synthesis tool always converts the RTL to equivalent equations. You choice is guided by whatever form makes it easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptions. Does it apply for sequential logic too? If we consider the same logic in always @ (posedge clk), will the same expression work. Please let me know what should be done for this issue considering the code to be sequential logic.

Comment: @AnirbanMoitra It doesn't matter. In general `c = &(a|b)` will be synthesized to 1x LUT4 and 1x LUT5 (I'm assuming width of 4 and Xilinx devices). When you want to use the register on the output then synthesis will add one more FF. That's it. Of course you will have one clock delay (for the `c` output). However, if the `c` is used in a combinatorial way somewhere else then inserting a flop here is better (you cut the logic levels and help P&R).

Answer (score 1):

Technically you dont care about the priority. You want c to be set to 0 only when any group of a[i] and b[i] equals 0, otherwise the c should be set to 1. This can be simplified to:

```
c = &(a|b);
```

Let's assume this:

```
reg [3:0] a = 'b0101;
reg [3:0] b = 'b1011;
```

Running this code:

```
initial begin 
    $display("%b", a);
    $display("%b", b);
    $display("%b", a|b);
    $display("%b", &(a|b));
end
```

will return 1 (yours else statement):

```
# 0101
# 1011
# 1111
# 1
```

But when we change values of a and b (a[1] and b[1] are 0s):

```
reg [3:0] a = 'b0101;
reg [3:0] b = 'b1001;
```

It will return:

```
# 0101
# 1001
# 1101
# 0
```

Exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic your final `else` with a *default assignment*:

```
always @ (*)
begin
    c = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<param; i++)
    begin
        if (~a[i] && ~b[i] )
          c = 0;
     end
end
```

Comment: This for loop will add number of if statements only. I need else if as well to ensure priority.

Comment: @AnirbanMoitra The _default assignment_  mimics the `else` statement; if all the bits of `a` and `b` are zero, then `c` will be `1`.

Comment: @AnirbanMoitra If you reverse the order of the loop then your logic synthesiser ought to synthesise exactly the same logic as your original `if` statements. This might be important if `a[0]` is later than `a[1]` and so on, but not if you're designing an FPGA, in which case LUTs will be used and the priority will be lost. It is important to emphasise that the boolean behaviour of each implementation will be identical.

Comment: The default statement is for else only. Still the else if are missing. This is for FPGA primarily. If all the expressions are identical (which is the case here), I lose the functionality. What I need is to stop evaluating the further conditions once it satisfies a condition. Then it goes back to 0 and starts checking again. Also I think I cannot have so many parallel conditions for the same output register.

Comment: @AnirbanMoitra I haven't simulated my code, because I am writing this on a mobile phone and it is a bit tricky to check, even with EDA Playground (note to self: make EDA Playground easier to use on a mobile phone). However, unless I have made some mistake, my code will simulate and synthesise on an FPGA exactly the same as yours. The order of evaluation is irrelevant (you are designing hardware not writing software) and as I keep saying, the else functionality is implemented by the default assignment. Please Google "default assignment" if you're unsure. Or how about trying it yourself?